# Adding acts_as_votable voting to posts and comments, routing issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use `acts_as_votable` voting system on both posts and comments in my rails app.  I am currently generating some obviously improper routes for my `comments#upvote` and `comments#downvote`, Here they are below:

```
upvote_post PUT    /posts/:id/upvote(.:format)                 comments#upvote

downvote_post PUT    /posts/:id/downvote(.:format)               comments#downvote
```

But they routes need to be something like `/posts/comment/:id/downvote`.  Here is how I am currently doing my routes

```
   resources :posts do
   member do
     put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
     put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
   end
   resources :comments
   member do 
     put "upvote", to: "comments#upvote"
     put "downvote", to: "comments#downvote"
   end
   end
```

Also, will I need two votes tables since I want both comments and posts to be votable?
Here is my my comments controller if needed:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
  def index
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @comments = @post.comments.order('created_at desc')
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:id])

  end


    def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

      @comment.post_id = @post.id 
      @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_comments_path(@post)
    else

      redirect_to new_post_comment_path(post)
    end
    end

  def destroy
  end

  def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to post_comments_path(@post)
  end

  def downvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.downvote_by current_user
    redirect_to post_comments_path(@post)
  end


 private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :post_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As a rule you probably don't want to nest your routes so deep. And the comment vote doesn't need to know the `id` of the post, just the comment. You also might find that rather than have a separate method for up and down voting in the controller having the votes go to the VotesController and just handle it there

So, I would do something like this:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :votes, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
end

resources :comment do
  resources :votes, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
end
```

That's if you want to have votes be a polymorphic relation on both in which case in your ApplicationsController you'd want a method like:

```
  def find_model
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id\z/
        return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
      end
    end
    nil
  end

# VotesController

def create
  model = find_model
  if model
   # do stuff
  end
end
```

If you have separate votes tables you can skip this last part.

Comment: What does the find model method do, and would I actually use the word model?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem fixed it by changing

```
put "like", to: "posts#upvote"  
put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote
```

to

```
get "like", to: "posts#upvote"  
get "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
```

**posts_controller**

```
def upvote
  @post.upvote_by current_user
  redirect_to :back
end

def downvote
  @post.downvote_by current_user
  redirect_to :back
end
```

**post show page**

```
<%= link_to "like", like_post_path(@post), method: :get %>
<%= link_to "dislike", dislike_post_path(@post), method: :get %>
```

hope this helps